# Error: The data used by step_impute_linear() did not have any rows where the imputation values were all complete

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, recipe, tidymodels

I am using the recipe function and get an error when using the `step_impute_linear()` inside of the recipe function to impute NA's. Note that `step_impute_median` or `step_impute_mean` work without a problem. Also it does not matter if I use:

- `step_impute_linear(all_predictors())` or,
- `step_impute_linear(all_numeric(),.)` etc.

None of the combinations work.

Also not that other methods like:

```
step_impute_knn(all_nominal(),impute_with = all_predictors(),-has_role("ID"))
```

fail too.

I also checked the data and not all of the rows contain missing data also not all of the columns do.

```
dt_rec <- recipe(
  OFFER_STATUS~ ., data = dt_training) %>% 
  # 1. Define Role
  update_role(MO_ID, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  update_role(SO_ID, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  # turn dates into decimals
  step_mutate_at(where(is.Date), fn = decimal_date) %>% 
  # impute all numeric columns with their median
  # 2. Impute
  # step_impute_median(all_numeric(),-has_role("ID"))%>%
  step_impute_linear(all_numeric(),impute_with = .,-has_role("ID"))
  # ignoring novel factors
  # 3. Handle factor levels
  step_novel(all_predictors(), -all_numeric())  %>%
  # impute all other nominal (character + factor) columns with the value "none"
  step_unknown(all_nominal(), new_level = "none") %>% 
  step_string2factor(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("ID")) %>% 
  # remove constant columns
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  # 4. Discretize
  # remove variables that have a high correlation with each other
  # as this will lead to multicollinearity
  step_corr(all_numeric(), threshold = 0.99) %>% 
  # normalization --> centering and scaling numeric variables
  # mean = 0 and Sd = 1
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  # 5. Dummy variables
  # creating dummary variables for nominal predictors
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes())
# 6. Normalization
# 7. Multivariate transformation
step_pca(all_numeric_predictors())

dt_rec

dt_rec %>% summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a [function like `step_impute_linear()`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_impute_linear.html), you are saying "impute the values for my variable with other variables". If some of those other variables *also* have missing data, the model is not going to be able to fit successfully. If you have a set of variables, say `x`, `y`, and `z`, that all have some missing data and that you want to impute using each other, I recommend that you:

- impute one or more of the variables (say `x`) with a method that only depends on **that variable**, like using the median or similar
- impute other variables using only the predictors that are now complete with no missing data (say impute `y` and `z` based on `x`)

It's not going to work out if you try to fit a whole set of linear models for a set of variables using each other, all of which have missing data.